# Why were the Levins kicked out of their hotel after one night?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-plot-against-america

In The Plot Against America, the Levin family checks into a decent-quality hotel (The Douglas which may be a real place maybe renamed) and they spend one night but when the return the manager tells them a mistake was made and they will have to leave -- the manager has repacked for them. But while courteous he is also cold and soon it escalates and the police are called.

The father pointed out that they had made reservations long ago and paid a deposit. He concludes this was due to antisemitism which in the story is in fact the case.

I am aware that hotels were "restricted", sometimes explicitly saying they wanted only Christian (and White) customers. (I think post ww2 this started to change but certainly it remained for years in various places -- it is well known that even Black entertainers appearing at a hotel could not stay at that hotel or if they did, had issues with using the pool and restaurants.) But given their surname, why give them the reservation in the first place or the room upon their arrival? (Assuming surname was not a giveaway, the family was supposed to appear Jewish -- at least the father is played by a Jew and the mother has played a Jew in other work of hers.)

Comment: releseabe, you can't really use American history/historical rules about racism and anti-Semitism, because this mini-series is set in an alternative universe. While President Lindburgh is shown as anti-Semitic, it is suggested that he wasn't enough. Acting President Wheeler actually starts rounding up Jews. So, we have no idea why, in such a world, any of the events you ask about would happen.